# Store multiple rows in multiple tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I want to store multiple rows in multiple tables within my database. My controller is currently not storing multiple values, it is only saving one row in  my `bill_products` and `item_lists` tables.

`purchases` table:

```
    |   product   quantity     price     manufacturer    |
    |     a           1         12$           xyz        |
    |     b           2         1$             x         |
    |     c           10        10$            y         |
```

`bill_products` table:

```
    |   product   quantity     price    |
    |    a           1         12$      |
    |    b           2         1$       |
    |    c           10        10$      |
```

`item_lists` table:

```
    |   product   quantity     |
    |    a           1         |
    |    b           2         |
    |    c           10        |
```

This is my `purchase\purchase-entry.blade.php`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">PURCHASE FORM</div>

                <div class="card-body">
            
                @if (Session::has('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">{!! Session::get('success') !!}</div>
                @endif
                @if (Session::has('failure'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{!! Session::get('failure') !!}</div>
                @endif
                         
    <form method="POST"   action="{{route('purchaseentryformsave')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @csrf
<div class="form-row">

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label >product NAME</label>
      <input type="text"  name="product[]"  placeholder="product" value="" required >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label >quantity</label>
      <input type="text"  name="quantity[]"  placeholder="quantity" value="" required >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label >price</label>
      <input type="text"  name="price[]"  placeholder=price" value="" required >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label >manufacturer</label>
      <input type="text"  name="manufacturer[]"  placeholder="manufacturer" value="" required >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="submit">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

The associated route:

```
Route::post('purchasesave', 'PurchaseController@purchasesave')->name('purchasesave');
```

My controller `PurchaseController.php` uses these 3 models: `Purchase` , `BillProduct` and `ItemList`.

```
    public function purchaseentryformsave(Request $request)
   {
     
    
    $input = $request->all();

$purchases = [];
$bill_products = [];
$item_lists = [];

foreach( $request->product as $k => $p ) {
    $data = collect([
        'product' => $request['product'][$k],
        'quantity' => $request['quantity'][$k],
        'price' => $request['price'][$k],
        'manufacturer' => $request['manufacturer'][$k],
    ]);
    $purchases[] = $data->toArray();
    $bill_products[] = $data->except(['manufacturer'])->toArray();
    $item_lists[] = $data->except(['price', 'manufacturer'])->toArray();
}

Purchases::insert( $purchases );
BillProduct::insert( $bill_products );
ItemList::insert( $item_lists );

       return redirect('allpurchasesupplierlist')->with('success','PURCHASE ENTRY ADDED SUCCESSFULLY .'); 
     }
```

models

**ItemList**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item_list extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'item_lists';
     protected $fillable = ['product','quantity'];
}
```

**Purchase**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Purchase extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'purchases';
     protected $fillable = ['product','quantity','price'.'manufacturer'];
}
```

**BillProduct**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Billproduct extends Model
{
     
     protected $table = 'bill_products';
     protected $fillable = ['product','quantity','price'];
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the array, or need to run a loop

Comment: @sta can you post answer

Comment: @sta can you post your answer please

Comment: @sta please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use `insert` instead of `create`

```
$purchases = [];
$bill_products = [];
$item_lists = [];

foreach( $request->product as $k => $p ) {
    $data = collect([
        'product' => $request['product'][$k],
        'quantity' => $request['quantity'][$k],
        'price' => $request['price'][$k],
        'manufacturer' => $request['manufacturer'][$k],
    ]);
    $purchases[] = $data->toArray();
    $bill_products[] = $data->except(['manufacturer'])->toArray();
    $item_lists[] = $data->except(['price', 'manufacturer'])->toArray();
}

Purchases::insert( $purchases );
BillProduct::insert( $bill_products );
ItemList::insert( $item_lists );
```

Comment: my form submitting 10 values in array, it was still storing single value in every time submit  in "ItemList" and "BillProduct"

Comment: just adjust the example above to your needs. and show your model and structure table.

Comment: i am not getting any error message. but multiple values are not storing in table it just storing form 1st inserted value

Comment: can you show your model of purchases, billproduct and itemlist?

Comment: after I make a simulation like yours, I can submitted 20 values data in array to Purchases, BillProducts, and ItemLists. your model name of Item_list not same as ItemList, rename class Item_list extends Model to class ItemList extends Model

Comment: i renamed class Item_list  to ItemList. but same problem multiple data not storing

Comment: your case is very strange. try composer dump-autoload. and try to insert only BillProduct::insert( $bill_products ); , uncomment Purchases::insert & ItemList::insert, and try again insert only ItemList::insert( $item_lists ); uncomment Purchases::insert & BillProduct::insert

Comment: i updated  my controller with your code can you check is there any problem in my controller thank you